# Asking a question to an answer

Tags: discussion, questions

I saw a question that had been answered already, and I posted a comment to that answer with another question.  It wasn't a question about clarification of the answer.  Would the better practice be to open a new question, or was it okay to ask the answerer a question?

The question/answer being mentioned: [Objective-C: initWithTitle:@"" and alertBox.title = @""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216273/objective-c-initwithtitle-and-alertbox-title/14216348#14216348)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't ask new questions in a comment on an old one, **just ask a new question.**

Note, that the only comment I see in there is you asking a clarification on an answer, and that's usually fine, though the author might not necessarily be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of question it is. If it's a question that would benefit the community and can actually be answered with a correct answer then it should be a new question, where you can reference the inspiration within the question text.

However, if your question is more of the "what page from the book you cite does this come from, as I have it at home and want to read it for myself" variety, or a "why don't you do it in {this manner} instead" then that's more suited as a comment against the answer because it doesn't have merit as a full question itself, but does add value to the answer you comment against.

Comment: That would be clarification, not a separate question.